# a lot of gc when using parseFrom(inputStream) on Android

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

Protocol Buffer lite: 2.5.0

When parsing an InputStream on Android I get a lot of gc.
The gc slows the process of receiving data and writing it to a DB a lot - what to do?

> GC freed 16514 objects / 714496 bytes in 81ms
>   GC freed 20570 objects / 888776 bytes in 90ms
>   GC freed 22768 objects / 908208 bytes in 99ms

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "protobuf.dat");
FileInputStream istream = new FileInputStream(f);
FooBar data = FooBar.parseFrom(istream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google-authored Java protobuf implementation is optimized for servers running on OpenJDK/HotSpot/etc., where allocating small short-lived objects is efficient.  Dalvik makes different performance trade-offs and may call for a different kind of implementation.  Unfortunately, there's not much you can do to make the Google implementation work better (it would probably require a deep re-design), but you could try some of the other Java protobuf implementations listed here to see if any of them perform better:

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns

In fact, it looks like *all* of the other Java implementations are explicitly designed for mobile environments.